# SpringBoot JPA / EclipseLink / Hikary unkown query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, hikaricp

I have an SprinBoot application which on startup seems to run some queries (We can see the in the db logs, not the spring boot logs).
I have no idea where there are comming from.

It seems to run this query for every datasource, they look like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID <> ID
```

Is there some kind of connection check/integretycheck or something similiar? I already looked into hikari but haven't found anything yet. I set connectionTestQuery to : SELECT 1 FROM DUAL. I did not help.

The database is an oracle DB. I use EclipseLink and hikari for the datasource connection.

Thanks for help or some hints.

Comment: Did someone maybe set the spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTestQuery in some config file, as I don't see anywhere that would default to using "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID <> ID". Logging might show which level is issuing the query though, but my guess is the datasource itself is validating the connections. Could be EclipseLink though too - check that it is using an OraclePlatform class. logging again will show it, or you can specify it using the "eclipselink.target-database" persistence property https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will search through all logs. Once I found the problem I post it here

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that EclipseLink has a method SchemaManager.checkTableExists, which checks if the table exists and if not creates it. I removed this from the application.yml

```
ddl-generation: create-tables
```

and it solved the problem